# Gradle Build Timeout for a Fragment Test

Tags: android, android-espresso, gui-testing

For some reason the status says `Gradle build Running` infinitely or it just times out.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class UserTest {

    @Test
    fun test_isMovie() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<UserList>()
    }
}
```

I do have another Instrumentation based Test class which runs fine, it's the individual Fragment test class that I'm having problems with.

**The dependencies for build.gradle (app)** looks like this. Please advise.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1'
debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5"
androidTestImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'
```

**build.gradle (app) looks like this**

```
android {
    namespace 'com.demo.example'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.example"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    } ...
```

Comment: Do you have this in your `build.gradle` ? 
testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

Comment: Yes, I do, updated my question.

Comment: Can you change `debugImplementation` to `androidTestImplementation` here ?
debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5"

Comment: It progressed a bit but then failed with the error message `Unable to resolve activity for: Intent`

Comment: Nice, can you post the error?

Comment: Add this 
debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0-beta01")

Comment: sorry for the delay, I tried but it didn't work, tried an updated version too. `debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0-alpha04")`. The Instrumentation used to work fine, and ceased to work with upgraded version of angroid.